# How can I delete sys.path.append("../") but not get ImportError: No module named XXX

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

python version : 2.7.15 on win7

`sys.path : ['', 'C:\\windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Users\\leih\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python27\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']`

My module tree as below:

```
├───dependency_resolver
│   ├───entrypoint
│   │       dependency.py
│   │       __init__.py
│   │
│   ├───test
│   │   │   test_dependency.py
│   │   │
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │           test_dependency.cpython-27-PYTEST.pyc
│   │
│   └───util
│           kube_util.py
│           kube_util.pyc
│           nc_util.py
│           pg_util.py
│           __init__.py
│           __init__.pyc
```

I want to import kube_util in dependency.py， if just `from util import kube_util` will get ImportError `ImportError: No module named util`，but if add `sys.path.append("../")`， it can be run. The same problem in test module.

```
import os, sys, time, json
# sys.path.append("../")
from util import kube_util
```

I see requests doesn't have `sys.path.append("../")` but can import module successful，so what can i do to delete `sys.path.append("../")` and get right result?

Comment: A useful read: https://realpython.com/python-modules-packages/

Comment: I tried `from dependency_resolver.util import kube_util`  get ImportError `No module named dependency_resolver.util` and also tried `from . import kube_util` at util/__init__.py, both of two ways failed.@Jean-François Corbett

Comment: Try adding a `__init__.py` file in your dependency_resolver folder

Comment: I tied this way but get the same error `ImportError: No module named dependency_resolver.uti` @Shashank Verma

Comment: I don't have a legacy Python (2) installation (and don't plan on installing it either), so I can't figure this out for you, unfortunately. Migrate to modern Python 3 if you can.

Comment: why if I run dependency.py as `python dependency.py` at the entrypoint folder or dependency_resolver parent folder will get ImportError, but run as `python -m dependency_resolver.entrypoint.dependency` at dependency_resolver parent folder will be fine. Now my python version is 3.5 and import code is `import dependency_resolver.util.kube_util as kube_util`@Jean-François Corbett

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute path of the module as below:

```
from dependency_resolver.util import kube_util
```

or you can also use relative import:

```
from ..util import kube_util
```

Comment: I tried to use the absolute path of the module  `from dependency_resolver.util import kube_util` but get `ImportError: No module named dependency_resolver.util`